# How to reroute a dial pattern to another phone number?

Tags: voip, telephony

In Asterisk/FreePBX you can add an outbound route with normal trunking and set a dial pattern like so, in order to reroute any call from `00316` to `08445930044` (a cheap public [access number](https://www.0044.co.uk/netherlands/cheap-international-calls) from GB > NL):

**Prepend:** `08445930044`

**Prefix:** `00316`

**Match pattern:** *Blank*

This works perfectly when dialling `00316`. The outbound call is rerouted to `08445930044` as expected.

How can this dial pattern be changed to also reroute calls made to `0031612345` to the new number of `08445930044`?

I tried changing the Match Pattern to `.` and `X.` but this made calls to `0031612345` unroutable.

I was able to get `003165`, `003166` and `003167` working (able to dial those numbers) by changing the Prefix to `00316[567]`, but changing the Prefix to `00316.` or `00316X.` makes calls to `003165` (or `00316123`) unroutable.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.